# My NERDTree opening two panes when I toggle it open

Tags: bash, vim, vi

I've installed and uninstalled NERDTree in my .vimrc using vim-plugged. For some reason on my PopOS terminal when I open it, it shows two panes instead of one. I have this installed on different machines the same way without two panes opening. Any idea why?

[image: image of my terminal after toggling NERDTree]

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I had a script in my .vimrc that was checking if it was open and if not, open it. Apparently, it wasn’t detecting it being open.